# Simple PHP code doesn't work

Tags: php

I've got some simple code written in PHP and I don't know why it won't work :(

First php file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once "php/codes.php"; ?>

 <ul>
<?php echo "<li><a href='' class='".whereAmI("files")."'>YYYYY</a></li> ";?>
<li><a href=''>XXXX</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

And second one (codes.php):

```
<?php
$menu= array("privileges","files", "posts", "menu");

    function whereAmI($addr){
        foreach ($menu as $value) {
            if($value===$addr) return "current"; 

    }
}
```

The problem is that the webpage doesn't show anything and I don't know why?

Comment: Enable error codes and you will see why

Comment: Try sticking this at the top of your code: ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

Comment: If its not executing, you either have an error, or your environment is not set up to execute php correctly.

Comment: Nothing has happened :(
So there is no error (if yes so why it doesn't work)?

Comment: By the way there is `in_array` function.

Comment: @PatLas, if I may direct your attention to the answer I gave below... the $menu variable is out of scope, it needs to be made global to be seen inside of the whereAmI function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I am against global variables, change your code to this:

```
<?php
$menu= array("privileges","files", "posts", "menu");

    function whereAmI($addr){
        global $menu;
        foreach ($menu as $value) {
            if($value===$addr) return "current"; 

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thans it works fine :)
Can you tell me why it is necessary to use "global"?

Answer (score 1):

In your function add `global $menu;`

Read up on [variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)